# innerHTML no me muestra el contenido de código php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo las siguientes lineas de código:

```
<?php
if(is_null($row['VideoS_user']) and $row['Coach_user']==0){
                    echo '<a href="#"onclick="populateData("ColabIni");" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Colaboraciones</a>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<a href="#"onclick="populateData("Colab");" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Colaboraciones</a>';
                }
?>

<script>
            var targetDiv = document.getElementById('content');
            var htmlContent = '';
            
            function populateData(idTipe){
           
              switch(idTipe){
                    case 'ColabIni':{
                 htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba</p> <img src="../img/prueba.png" alt="">';
    
                  break;
                }
                      case 'Colab':{
                 htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba</p> <img src="../img/prueba.png" alt="">';
    
                  break;
                }
                default:
    console.log('Lo lamentamos, por el momento no disponemos de ' + idTipe + '.');
            break;

              }
              targetDiv.innerHTML = htmlContent;
            }
    </script>
```

El probelma esta en que al presionar en los hipervinculos VideoS o VideoIni el contenido no aparece, ni cambia, al principio la pagina colapsaba, pero al poner " " en el parametro de populatedata() se ha solucionado, aun asi no me muestra el contenido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente estas haciendo uso incorrecto de las comillas y no estas dejando el espacio requerido entre las propiedades de HTML en este código:

```php
if(is_null($row['VideoS_user']) and $row['Coach_user']==0){
    echo '<a href="#"onclick="populateData("ColabIni");" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Colaboraciones</a>';
}else{
    echo '<a href="#"onclick="populateData("Colab");" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Colaboraciones</a>';
}
```

Debes agregare estos cambios:

```php
echo '<a href="#" onclick="populateData(\'ColabIni\')" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Colaboraciones</a>';
echo '<a href="#" onclick="populateData(\'Colab\')" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Colaboraciones</a>';
```

- He agregado el espacio entre las propiedades `href` y `onclick`.
- Y además he cambiado las comillas dobles por comillas simples escapadas para que no interfieran con las comillas simples de PHP.
- Tampoco veo necesario el `;` en el llamado a las funciones.

Eso problablemente solvente tu error, si hay algo más o tienes más errores dejamelos saber en los comentarios.